# C++ Convert .jpg to .png using OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, file-type, imread

I am writing in C++ and trying to use OpenCV imread() and imwrite() to convert an image from .jpg to .png filetype and save it in the same location as the original file.

When testing the code with a .png file (just to see if a new file is produced at all), a new file is produced and saved.

When testing the code with a .jpg, no new file is produced.

The code I have so far is:

```
int main(int argc, char *arvg[])
{
    Mat newImg = imread(arvg[1]);
    string new_filename = "source/newfile.png";

    imwrite(new_filename,newImg,CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION,9)
}
```

The .jpg image I am trying to convert is a 16kb image.

Am I overlooking a step or is there a better way to carry out this process?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing the parameter `CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION` and its value when writing a **jpg** file?

Comment: Yes, I just tried that now.  It still produces and saves no file at all.

Comment: It will however convert a .png to a .jpg when I change the extension in the file name.

Comment: Does the folder source exist inside the current folder? Was the file actually read?

Comment: you can't use imwrite like `imwrite(new_filename,newImg,CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION,9)` are you sure the code in the question is correct?

Comment: @sturkmen... You are right. Additional arguments are given in the form of an `std::vector` like this. `imwrite(new_filename,newImg,{ CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION,9 } );`

Comment: Thank you for your input.  It seemed it was the image I was trying to convert that was the problem.  When I attempted with alternate images it was successful (not sure why that JPG in particular wouldn't convert).  The code was correct, I didn't need to introduce curly brackets, but I did introduce the use of a vector as advised by sgarizvi just to be sure no other issues would arise.